# Where do I turn to in Eastern philosophy in this case?

Tags: belief, eastern-philosophy

In Western philosophy, every belief one holds is scrutinized.

However, it seems to me that there is more room for accepting seemingly self-evident philosophical beliefs in Eastern philosophy.

Can you suggest me places to look for this sort of acceptance? I am talking about the primacy of intuition over reasoning.

Comment: Not very clear... what is the opinion considered?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA to answer my question this detail does not matter, as I said in the question. You can consider my view to be some arbitrary philosophical belief that is not a basic belief (to use the jargon of Western philosophy).

Comment: But also Western phil is interested to self-evidence; see e.g. [Husserl](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2107257?seq=1)

Comment: I think sometimes people downvote just because they can.

Comment: The use of the term 'shelter' is confusing. Are you trying to shelter an ostensibly self-evident view from critical analysis? I suggest a big rewrite of the question. If you don't think the particular view matters, then don't mention it; just start with 'can an abstract philosophical idea' and ask your question.

Comment: @TedWrigley I think the same thing, so I have rewritten the question entirely.

Comment: It's really not easy to understand your question. Do you mean some kind of stance that intuition is more fundamental than reasoning? Euclid's axioms were considered self-evident, though our being in Minkowski space showed Euclid's are just one possible set. Many monotheistic thinkers such as Descartes focus on what is self-evident ('clear and distinct perceptions' of the 'inextensible' mental world). I can't see what you are getting at, so voted to close. I suggest you just state the stance you wish to argue for, so we can understand your motivation.

Comment: @CriglCragl true, made the question clearer.

Comment: It seems u hope to grasp a philosophy which has "primacy of intuition over reasoning"? But isn't this itself need reasoning to explain why? This is like many people think no need to learn philosophy, but when pressured upon a reason, they still need to invoke some kind of personal informal or immature "philosophy". Intuition is not at odds with reasoning at all, instead reasoning is required in any sound philosophy, be it internalism or externalism...

Comment: Pragmatism or dogmatism, confucionism or stoicism. Something like that? The Greek tended to be quite pragmatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, Eastern philosophy isn't about intuition *per se*. It's more at *apperception*. Western philosophy tries to put the world into language; Eastern philosophy starts from the idea that language is unsuited to the task, and reaches for a more direct understanding of the world.

In the Eastern worldview, what we call 'intuition' would arise from that direct understanding of the world. There's nothing particularly special about it; it's just a clear understanding of how *this* affects *that*, without relying on some mathematical or linguistic approximation.

Comment: Adding some observation based on your above sensible logic expressed out of language, eastern philosophers tend to say less (intentionally with the understanding public language is like 2-edge sword and philosophy's ultimate goal is private improvement anyway), while western philosophers tend to write and say  a lot cautiously (with the emphasis of logic and want to get criticized and learn from others via innately developed and shared concepts)...

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find advocacy for abandonment of views rather than acceptance of them.

[Paramatthaka Sutta: On Views](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.05.irel.html)

> That brahmana who does not grasp at a view, with what could he be
> identified in the world?

[The Vagrakkhedikâ or Diamond-Cutter](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/sbe49/sbe4929.htm) VII.

> As I, O Bhagavat, understand the meaning of the preaching of the
> Bhagavat, there is nothing that was known by the Tathâgata under the
> name of the highest perfect knowledge, nor is there anything that is
> taught by the Tathâgata.

Comment: Are you implying there is nothing like what I'm looking for in Eastern thought?

Comment: I guess so.  In this way, views are not scrutinized; you are peacefully unbadgered.  It might look like something has been accepted but perhaps no one is really taking anything to heart in the samsara of views.

Comment: "One learns that all is mere fluff, that nothing is worth adhering to, nothing is worth clinging to, as what one adheres to and clings to gains consistency by that very adhering to it by one and that very clinging to it by one, but that that consistency is quite fluffy and doesn't hold, that it slips away as one tries to adhere to it, to cling to it. So one learns to deal with everything as fluff and nothing more." - Tang Huyen ([alt.zen](https://alt.zen.narkive.com/NNaoi3Gu/tang-gets-caught-in-his-own-trap#post76))

Comment: "*Fluff, fluff, all is fluffy and a striving after the mind.*"

Answer (score 0):

Might you mean something like Taoism?

Opening lines of the [Tao Te Ching](https://www.wussu.com/laotzu/) by Lao Tzu:

> "The Tao that can be told is not the eternal Tao. The name that can be
> named is not the eternal name. The nameless is the beginning of heaven
> and earth. The named is the mother of ten thousand things. Ever
> desireless, one can see the mystery. Ever desiring, one can see the
> manifestations. These two spring from the same source but differ in
> name;
> this appears as darkness. Darkness within darkness. The gate to all mystery."

From the poem '[Xinxin Ming](https://web.csulb.edu/%7Ewweinste/HsinHsinMing.html)', (Verses on Faith in Mind) by Third Chinese Zen Patriarch Jianzhi Sengcan:

> "The Great Way is not difficult for those who have no preferences.
> When love and hate are both absent, everything becomes clear and
> undisguised.  Make the smallest distinction, however, and heaven and
> earth are set infinitely apart. If you wish to see the truth, then
> hold no opinions for, or against, anything.  To set up what you like
> against what you dislike is the disease of the mind.  When the deep
> meaning of things is not understood, the mind's essential peace is
> disturbed to no avail.
>
> "The Way is perfect, like vast space where nothing is lacking and
> nothing is in excess.  Indeed, it is due to our choosing to accept or
> reject that we do not see the true nature of things.  Live neither in
> the entanglements of outer things, nor in inner feelings of emptiness.
> Be serene in the oneness of things, and such erroneous views will
> disappear by themselves.  When you try to stop activity to achieve
> passivity, your very effort fills you with activity.  As long as you
> remain in one extreme or the other, you will never know Oneness.
>
> Those who do not live in the single Way fail in both activity and
> passivity, assertion and denial.  To deny the reality of things is to
> miss their reality; to assert the emptiness of things is to miss their
> reality.  The more you talk and think about it, the further astray you
> wander from the truth.  Stop talking and thinking, and there is
> nothing you will not be able to know."

I fear though that you are orientalising, mistaking mystic thinking like this, as being without 'scrutiny', whatever you mean by that. These foundational texts above embody sophisticated reactions to ongoing debates and practices, just like Western philosophical and religious treaties. [This article](https://absoluteirony.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/nagarjuna-nietzsche-rorty-and-their-strange-looping-trick/amp/) draws parallels between the thinking of Buddhist philosopher Nagarjuna, and more recent Western philosophers, in regard to a kind of non-dual using thinking to escape thinking, eg 'Wittgenstein's Ladder'.

Mysticism has been part of Western thinking, such as Anchorite practices and the Desert Fathers, and hesychasm chanting in the Eastern Orthodox church, and Sufism which started in Turkey. But the rise of centralised militaristic states, and of technology and science, pushed these strands to the margins in a way that did not happen in India & China. In contrast, China institutionally suppressed their school of logic, Mohism.

Comment: This is an interesting read, but not an answer to my question. I made my question clearer.

Comment: @Alex: Have you looked at moral & mathematical intuitionism?

Comment: I have not, no.